# Delete items from table without a reference ID

Tags: sql

I need to delete all the Contributors that don't have a License assigned to them

```
Table        : Columns

Contributors : [id, Name,...]
Licenses     : [id, ContributorId, Name, ...]
```

Something like this

```
DELETE FROM Contributors
WHERE
License.ContributorId != Contributor.Id
```

Comment: You may well want to backup your database before testing whatever `DELETE` command you are trying to work out.  `DELETE` is not a command you want to be making multiple attempts at. ;-)

Comment: An ORM solution is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will work if you are using SQL Server:

```
DELETE Contributors 
FROM Contributors as c
LEFT JOIN License as l
ON c.id = l.ContributorID
WHERE l.id is null
```

A good test to do before actually doing the delete is to replace the `DELETE Contributors` line with `SELECT *`.  This will show you all the records that are about to be deleted, so it's a nice sanity check...

So your sanity check would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Contributors as c
LEFT JOIN License as l
ON c.id = l.ContributorID
WHERE l.id is null
```

Comment: I cant get it do delete anything... it always says timeout expired... weird thing is when I try the 'sanity check' it returns A LOT of rows... :s

Comment: How many records are you trying to delete?  Where are you running the query from?

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM Contributors
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM License
  WHERE License.ContributorId = Contributors.Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 DELETE FROM Contributors
    WHERE Contributors.Id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT License.ContributorId FROM License)
```